# Convert datetime and timezone to datetime in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, timezone, datetime

How to convert datetime with timezone to datetime. I have tried multiple which are available on PHP blog. But nothing worked out. I am retrieving datetime from MySql query as `2017-01-20T13:59:19+03:00` format. But it shows the time zone separately as `+03:00`. Actually the correct time is `2017-01-20 16:59:19`.

So how can I show the correct **time with adding GMT time in the datetime stamp**.

Comment: How about your issue?

Comment: Not yet solved.. Still trying with other ways

Answer (score 5):

Try This

```
protected $timezone;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
......
)
{
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
}

$dateTimeZone = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($yourdate))->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 4):

1) We can use the PHP basic: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

```
<?php

$datetime = new DateTime('2017-01-20T13:59:19+03:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));

$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
print $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s (e)');
//Output 2017-01-20 05:59:19 (America/New_York)
```

Or

```
$date = '2017-01-20T13:59:19+03:00';
$convertdate = (new \DateTime())->setTimestamp(strtotime($date));
$d = $convertdate->format(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT);
//Output string '2017-01-20 10:59:19'
```

2) Magento provides some standard date time classes which we can find under `vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/DateTime`.

For example: `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Timezone`

Inject `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface` in our constructor:

```
protected $timezone;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
......
)
{
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
}
```

We can use:

```
$this->timezone->date($date)->format(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT);
```

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me

```
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone
$this->timezone = $timezone

$localizedDateTimeISO = $this->timezone->date(new \DateTime($repliedAt))->format(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT);
```

Answer (score 2):

instantiate

```
protected $_date;
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date)
{
  $this->_date =  $date;
}
```

and use in your function

```
$this->_date->date()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = '2018-01-29 13:10:20';
    $this->formatDate(
                    $this->_localeDate->date(new \DateTime($date)),
                    \IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
                    true
                );
        public function formatDate(
            $date = null,
            $format = \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
            $showTime = false,
            $timezone = null
        ) {
            $date = $date instanceof \DateTimeInterface ? $date : new \DateTime($date);
            return $this->_localeDate->formatDateTime(
                $date,
                $format,
                $showTime ? $format : \IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
                null,
                $timezone
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$timezoneInterface = new \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
$dateTimeZone = $timezoneInterface->date($yourDate)->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get Current Store Date Time by injecting in your class constructor in instance of `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface` and use that one to get the DateObject.

For example:

```
protected $timezone;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->timezone = $timezone;
    ....
}
```

And then you can use it as followed:

```
$date = $this->timezone->formatDate();
```

For more information about different formats you can take a look at this article I wrote https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-get-current-store-date-time/

Comment: Thank u @Mr.Lewis. I will go through it..