# Magento2 convert UTC time to IST

Tags: magento2, timezone, datetime, format

Can anyone let me know how to change UTC time from table column to IST(Indian Standard time) programatically with Datetime format?

I have currently following date time value available in UTC format and i need to convert it into Indian Standard Time in Magento2:

2018-09-18 11:13:07 AM (UTC)

it should convert to IST with following:

2018-09-18 04:43:07 PM (IST)

Comment: Hey You can reefer this solution it will work.
[Magento 2 Date time timezone](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155737/convert-datetime-and-timezone-to-datetime-in-magento-2/164047)

Comment: I have tried with following from your mentioned reference:
$this->_localeDate->date(new \DateTime($historyDate))->format('m/d/y H:i:s');
but its not converting to IST, don't we need to set timezone anywhere like something?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can set timezone from admin panel.

Go to **Store->configuration->Genral** You will find time zone according to your store you can set timezone.

Comment: Yes correct but i want to convert my custom date into IST time with datetime format, actually order created date is in UTC timeformat and i want to show it with IST timezone also so that admin can know exact indian standard time with which order was placed.

Comment: If you want to do it in custom way then you can use PHP core time/date function.For exmple:

$date = new DateTime('2012-07-16 01:00:00 +00');

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2012-07-15 05:00:00

This might help you!!

Comment: i have tried with above code:
$date = new \DateTime($historyDate); 
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

but its not converting to IST as i need

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution below:

```
$date = new \DateTime($historyDate.' +00'); 
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata')); 
return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

this will always convert UTC to IST time